# How to create layout in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am Trying to create dashboard in zend framework but CSS and JAVA SCRIPT are not working?

Comment: "NOT WORKING" means ?? Are JS and CSS file are not getting included??  Explain your issues with more details and code snippets which will help us to address your issue.

Comment: I have create asset folder inside public directory, and there i put the css. but if i want to call this css in our phtml file so its not working

Comment: Have you tried with code given by @Ismail  below??  You can use this code in phtml files to include JS and CSS files.

Comment: Yes i try, but still not working, i put this code in our layout.phtml but not working.

Comment: Try with ``echo $this->headLink()   ->prependStylesheet($this->baseUrl('assets/css/style.css'));`` 

  ``echo  $this->headScript()->prependFile($this->baseUrl('assets/js/script.js'))``

Comment: please tell me one thing, i am creating a class in css file, but its not working if i give the name in phtml file.

Comment: Check the page source and see if the included css files appear or not.  If they appear, then click on css file, it should show the css file content

Comment: Check the page source and see if the included css files appear or not.  If they appear, then click on css file, it should show the css file content

Comment: Means if i have login.phtml file, so top of this file we have to mention about  css file.?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79298/discussion-between-sameer-k-and-anil-bhadula).

Answer (score 0):

Create folder in public directory like assets. then add below code in your view file.

```
  <?php

   $this->headLink()
    ->prependStylesheet($this->baseUrl('assets/css/style.css'));
   $this->headScript()
    ->prependFile($this->baseUrl('assets/js/script.js'))
   ?>
```

Note: change file names with your file names.

Comment: I have create a assets folder inside the public, and include there style.css, but if i want to use this css in our phtml file so its not working?  any configration required?

Comment: did you add above script in your .phtml file?